# Force mysql to return no result on bit_or

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mysql query that uses bit_or on a result set. When there is no result set, the bit_or function returns 0 (this is correct as per the mysql documentation).

For example:

```
select n from t1 where a=1;
```

Returns no rows.

```
select bit_or(n) from t1 where a=1;
```

Returns 0

I need to force the last query to instead return no result from the bit_or query, e.g. (in pseudo-code, because I do not know the correct invocation):

```
select bit_or(n) unless 0 from t1 where a=1;
```

Does anybody know how I can do this? (Clarification, I need the "no result on 0" return value for an external program, which unfortunately cannot be changed).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `case` statement to `null` out the row, like so:

```
select
    case 
        when bit_or(n) = 0 then null
        else bit_or(n)
    end
from
    t1
where
    a=1
```

Or, if you want to completely ignore the row, you can do it in the `having` clause:

```
select
    bit_or(n)
from
    t1
where
    a=1
having
    bit_or(n) <> 0
```

The `having` clause is used to essentially do a `where` on aggregate columns (such as a `sum` or a `max`). In this case, your aggregate column is a `bit_or`. If you have additional columns in your result set, you will need to include them in the `group by` statement after the `where` clause, but before the `having` clause.

The first example will return `null` for that row, while the second example won't return the row if `bit_or(n)` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT BIT_OR(`n`) AS `bit`
    FROM `t1`
    WHERE `a` = 1
) AS `bit`
WHERE `bit`
```